# How to test local gradle plugin that depends on android plugin?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, plugins, spock

I am using this project to start a gradle plugin development : https://github.com/int128/gradle-plugin-starter

In this project, there are two kinds of tests :

- Unit test using spock
- Acceptance tests using gradle test kit

My plugin aims to configure android plugin. It is for internal use. We have a lot of projects that are configured in a same way so I want to use the same code base to do that.

Let's say that my plugin code is as follow :

```
class CopperPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
@Override
void apply(Project project) {
    if(!project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") && !project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")){
        throw new GradleScriptException("Android plugin needs to be applied first", new ClassNotFoundException())
    }
}
```

}

I don't know how to make acceptance test working !!! **Error** is :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'fixture-42'.
Plugin with id 'fr.coppernic.android' not found.
```

Acceptance test code is

```
@Unroll
def 'acceptance test should pass on Gradle #gradleVersion'() {
    given:
    def runner = GradleRunner.create()
        .withProjectDir(new File("fixture-${gradleVersion.replace(".","")}"))
        .withArguments('test')
        .withPluginClasspath()
        .withGradleVersion(gradleVersion)

    when:
    runner.build()

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()

    where:
    gradleVersion << ['4.2', '3.5']
}
```

acceptance test **build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }
}

gradlePlugin {
    pluginSourceSet parent.sourceSets.main
}
```

**build.gradle** from `fixture-35` folder

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://arti-01:8081/artifactory/plugins-release' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin:'com.android.application'
apply plugin:'fr.coppernic.android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
}

task test << {
    assert project.plugins.hasPlugin('fr.coppernic.android')
}
```

**build.gradle** from `fixture-42` folder

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://arti-01:8081/artifactory/plugins-release' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'fr.coppernic.android'

task test << {
    assert project.plugins.hasPlugin('fr.coppernic.android')
}
```

Comment: Have you created a `fr.coppernic.android.properties` in `src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins` with the correct `implementation-class` entry?`

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Yes I have !

Answer (score 1):

`GradleTestKit` only looks in the `plugins` DSL definition. You are applying your plugin through the `apply plugin:` syntax which wouldn't work.